# Get GUID of SharePoint list using jQuery

Tags: document-library, jquery, guid

I have different sites like

- `http://SP.abc.com/SPSite1`
- `http://SP.abc.com/SPSite2`
- `http://SP.abc.com/SPSite3`

and each having one Library with the same name called **Lib1**. Now I want to get **GUID** of this library using jquery or using any other method that is on client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it using REST query. The code should  be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    GetListGuid('Lib1');
});

function GetListGuid(listTitle){
    try {
    //REST Query to get the List Title 
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listTitle+"')?$select=Id",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert(data.d.Id);
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.error("Error.");
        }
    });
}
catch (ex) {
    alert(ex);
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Nice Solution added by @**users1100** for SharePoint 2013.

You can try JSOM also. It will work for both 2010 & 2013.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Name of List or Library');
clientContext.load(oList)
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    console.log(oList.get_id())
}, function() {
    // error handler
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On a page with the ListView WebPart displayed the listGUID is available as

```
ctx.listName
```

[image]